# D3 text wrap with text-anchor: middle

Tags: d3.js, word-wrap

In D3 I would like to wrap texts which have a middle text anchor. I looked at [this example from Mike Bostok](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7555321) but I cannot wrap my head around the settings.

I would like to see the text to be in the center (horizontal and vertical) of the red box.

```
var plot = d3.select(container)
  .insert("svg")
  .attr('width', 100)
  .attr('height', 200);

plot.append("text")
  .attr("x", 50)
  .attr("y", 100)
  .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
  .attr("alignment-baseline", "alphabetic")
  .text("The brown fox jumps!")
  .call(wrap, 100);


function wrap(text, width) {
  text.each(function() {
    var text = d3.select(this),
      words = text.text().split(/\s+/).reverse(),
      word,
      line = [],
      lineNumber = 0,
      lineHeight = 1.1, // ems
      y = text.attr("y"),
      dy = 1,
      tspan = text.text(null).append("tspan").attr("x", 0).attr("y", y).attr("dy", dy + "em");
    while (word = words.pop()) {
      line.push(word);
      tspan.text(line.join(" "));
      if (tspan.node().getComputedTextLength() > width) {
        line.pop();
        tspan.text(line.join(" "));
        line = [word];
        tspan = text.append("tspan").attr("x", 0).attr("y", y).attr("dy", ++lineNumber * lineHeight + dy + "em").text(word);
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Given the pointers from [Shashank](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5569282/shashank) I was now able to position the text central with the translate method. Just setting the y of the text didn't seem to change anything. I also added a yTrack variable to be able to continue drawing below the wrapped text.

```js
let yTrack = 100,
  plot = d3.select(container)
  .insert("svg")
  .attr('width', 100)
  .attr('height', 200);

plot.append("text")
  .attr("x", 50)
  .attr("y", yTrack)
  .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
  .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
  .text("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.")
  .call(wrap, 100);

let height = parseInt(plot.select('text').node().getBoundingClientRect().height);

plot.select("text").attr('transform', 'translate(0, ' + (-height / 2) + ')');

//plot.select("text").attr('y', 0);

yTrack += (parseInt(height / 2) + 10);

plot.append('rect')
  .attr("x", 0)
  .attr("y", yTrack)
  .attr("width", 100)
  .attr("height", 10)
  .style('fill', '#999');

function wrap(text, width) {
  text.each(function() {
    let text = d3.select(this),
      words = text.text().split(/\s+/).reverse(),
      word,
      line = [],
      lineNumber = 0,
      lineHeight = 1.1, // ems
      x = text.attr("x"),
      y = text.attr("y"),
      dy = 1.1,
      tspan = text.text(null).append("tspan").attr("x", x).attr("y", y).attr("dy", dy + "em");
    while (word = words.pop()) {
      line.push(word);
      tspan.text(line.join(" "));
      if (tspan.node().getComputedTextLength() > width) {
        line.pop();
        tspan.text(line.join(" "));
        line = [word];
        tspan = text.append("tspan").attr("x", x).attr("y", y).attr("dy", ++lineNumber * lineHeight + dy + "em").text(word);
      }
    }
  });
}
```

```css
#container {
  height: 200px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Regulär svg Text cannot be easily repositioned. You might look into putting your text into a <foreignObject>. Then you can use css and html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/text-anchor) for **text-anchor**, `middle` will result in the following:

> The rendered characters are aligned such that the **middle of the text string is at the current text position**.

and in your case, as you are breaking down the text into `tspan`s with `x` equal to `0` -- the **current text position** would be the start of the svg (i.e. at point 0). Also, the `x:50` applied to the `text` element wouldn't matter at all.

1. One approach would be to apply the center value i.e. 50 to the `tspan`s:

   ```
   tspan.attr("x", 50)
   ```

   Here's a snippet doing that:

   ```js
   var plot = d3.select(container)
     .insert("svg")
     .attr('width', 100)
     .attr('height', 200);

   plot.append("text")
     .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
     .attr("alignment-baseline", "alphabetic")
     .text("The brown fox jumps!")
     .call(wrap, 100);

   var height = plot.select('text').node().getBoundingClientRect().height;
   plot.select('text').attr('y', 100-height/2);

   function wrap(text, width) {
     text.each(function() {
       var text = d3.select(this),
         words = text.text().split(/\s+/).reverse(),
         word,
         line = [],
         lineNumber = 0,
         lineHeight = 0.1, // ems
         y = text.attr("y"),
         dy = 1,
         tspan = text.text(null).append("tspan").attr("x", 50).attr("y", y).attr("dy", dy + "em");
       while (word = words.pop()) {
         line.push(word);
         tspan.text(line.join(" "));
         if (tspan.node().getComputedTextLength() > width) {
           line.pop();
           tspan.text(line.join(" "));
           line = [word];
           tspan = text.append("tspan").attr("x", 50).attr("y", y).attr("dy", ++lineNumber * lineHeight + dy + "em").text(word);
         }
       }
     });
   }
   ```

   ```css
   #container {
     height: 200px;
     width: 100px;
     border: 1px solid red;
   }
   ```

   ```html
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
   <div id="container"></div>
   ```
2. Another approach would be to apply 'transform' property to the text in the following way:

   ```
   plot.select('text').attr('transform', 'translate(50, ' + (100-height/2)+')');
   ```

   Here's a snippet with this method:

   ```js
   var plot = d3.select(container)
     .insert("svg")
     .attr('width', 100)
     .attr('height', 200);

   plot.append("text")
     .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
     .attr("alignment-baseline", "alphabetic")
     .text("The brown fox jumps!")
     .call(wrap, 100);

   var height = plot.select('text').node().getBoundingClientRect().height;
   plot.select('text').attr('transform', 'translate(50, ' + (100-height/2)+')');

   function wrap(text, width) {
     text.each(function() {
       var text = d3.select(this),
         words = text.text().split(/\s+/).reverse(),
         word,
         line = [],
         lineNumber = 0,
         lineHeight = 0.1, // ems
         y = text.attr("y"),
         dy = 1,
         tspan = text.text(null).append("tspan").attr("x", 0).attr("y", y).attr("dy", dy + "em");
       while (word = words.pop()) {
         line.push(word);
         tspan.text(line.join(" "));
         if (tspan.node().getComputedTextLength() > width) {
           line.pop();
           tspan.text(line.join(" "));
           line = [word];
           tspan = text.append("tspan").attr("x", 0).attr("y", y).attr("dy", ++lineNumber * lineHeight + dy + "em").text(word);
         }
       }
     });
   }
   ```

   ```css
   #container {
     height: 200px;
     width: 100px;
     border: 1px solid red;
   }
   ```

   ```html
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
   <div id="container"></div>
   ```

In both of the above approaches, I'm not using the y-center value i.e. **100** instead I'm calculating the mid-point based on the text height as well using `getBoundingClientRect()` function.

```
var height = plot.select('text').node().getBoundingClientRect().height;
plot.select('text').attr('y', 100-height/2);
```

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: Genius... Thanks a lot. Method 2 (translate) does exactly what I need so I will go with that. Any idea why even if I use plot.select("text").attr('y', 0); the y location of the text drawn does not change at all? Maybe I am missing an update statement. Pretty new to D3 myself.

Comment: Glad I could help. That's because the text is being translated to `(100-height/2)` which defines the new starting point i.e. if `y` is set to `0`, it will move no further from the center of the rect. Try setting `y` to `10` and you'll see how the text offsets. If you're using [translate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/transform)  and you want to place the text at the top, just use `translate(50, height/2)`.